# Diff between declaring in file scope and implementation

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I am new to Objective-C and I was going through the [code](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads/blob/e8a9d68cd9b0a7d289ead366e6a427339f875f4c/ios/ThreadManager.m) when I came across this:

```
@implementation ThreadManager

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

NSMutableDictionary *threads;
```

Can I write this as:

```
@implementation ThreadManager {
    NSMutableDictionary *_threads;
    RCTBridge *_bridge;
}
```

Also can someone look at the code and please let me know if `@synthesize bridge = _bridge;` is actually being used? I think it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, these are different things.

`@synthesize` creates accessors (`-bridge` and `-setBridge:`). Declaring an ivar in `@implementation` does not.

This style of `@synthesize` is not common today, and generally is unnecessary <strike>(as written, it's almost certainly the default for this property)</strike> (*). But it isn't replaced by an `@implementation` ivar. It's replaced by nothing. You just have to declare the `@property`. That said, it isn't hurting anything. See [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9) for details.

(*) I looked up the code you referenced, and I see why they're using `@sythesize`. `bridge` is declared in a protocol, not directly in the interface, so it is needed in this case.

`threads` here is a class variable, shared by all instances of ThreadManager (it's more typical to make these `static`, but it's not mandatory; in this form it's really just a global, but in practice that's the same thing). This isn't really an "Objective-C thing." It works just like regular C. Your modified code makes it an instance variable, which is different.

Declaring ivars in `@implementation` is pretty rare in modern ObjC. The only reason I've done it in years is to hold C++ properties in objects that expose pure-ObjC interfaces, or very occasionally to hold a private C-type that I want to manipulate directly (without accessors). The `@property` syntax is much nicer and more common.